# help with table views on a uitabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

im writing a news app, and im just planning it out in my head and need some help, before i start coding.

my app is a tab bar controller that is loading and displaying info from an xml feed. i am going to start the download of the xml within the app delegate in the background, so the app does not get closed down by the os, however this means that when my first table loads it will be blank , so i need a way of reloading the table once it has finished . i have encountered this issue before and couldnt work a way round it

last time i started the download of the info from the viewdidload method in the first view controller and tried a reloaddata , but that didn't seem to work. has anyone got a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[yourTable reloadData]` is the way to go.

Make sure to call it on the main thread, and that your data structure is actually holding the correct data.